# Excel - Advanced Filter does not work with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

I have these dates (dateIni and DateFim)  formated as custom "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm".

[image]

1) When I execute the advanced filter I get the "Expected Result" on the  'Extract'. **OK**.

2) I Have recorded these steps and I got the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("Table35[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
        Range("O5:Q6"), CopyToRange:=Range("S5:U5"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

3) When I run this macro **I get nothing**!

What seems to be the problem?

Regrads,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might want to change `Dateini` to `DateIni` (in fourth column of image). Also, is there a seconds component to any/all of the date times (which isn't being displayed due to default number formatting) -- or all the seconds definitely zero?

Comment: Also, you might be comparing dates in first three to columns to just literal strings (in criteria columns). Try changing `DateIni` criteria to `="<=" & (date(2018,11,30) + time(10,37,0))`. Similar thing for `DateFin` criteria column `=">=" & (date(30/11/2018) + time(10,39,0))` -- and see if you get different results.

Comment: chillin I just tested and it does no work.Can I send you the workbook on an email so you can see for yourself?

Comment: If you have Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive/somewhere you can upload it to, maybe upload it there and edit your answer to include a link. I'm on a smartphone, so I can't open/test fully -- but other people on desktop will be able to see for themselves.

Comment: Here is a Goolgle Drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xHve4fRbl6VMQe2giLxK2qVdnIJN3Oo0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i believe that the date format is being changed when the macro run from dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm to mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm